# pass selected value Id from parent to child Kendo DropdownList

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, kendo-ui

I have a cascade Kendo DropdownList using jquery and Kendo UI. My problem is that I want to pass the selected value Id from Parent to child, which means pass StateId to city DropdownList and filters cities based on selected StateId but when I tried to debug it I faced something weird which was that the StateId is null. Is there anyone who could help me? Thanks.

```cs
   [HttpPost]
       public async Task<JsonResult> GetCities(DataSourceRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            request.Skip = 0;
            request.Take = 2000;

            var city = await _cityService.GetCities(request, cancellationToken);

            return Json(city);
        }
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

as you can see the value is null and this is my jquery part of code...

```js
 $("#drpState").kendoDropDownList({
                optionLabel: "States...",
                delay: 10,
                dataTextField: "Name",
                dataValueField: "StateId",
                dataSource: {
                    type: "json",
                    serverFiltering: true,
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            headers: {
                                "__RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val()
                            },
                            type: "Post",
                            dataType: "json",
                            url: "/Supervision/Tracking/GetStates",
                        }
                    },
                    schema: { data: 'Data' }
                },
            }).data("kendoDropDownList");


            $("#drpCity").kendoDropDownList({
                cascadeFrom: "drpState",
                optionLabel: "Cities...",
                delay: 10,
                dataTextField: "Name",
                dataValueField: "CityId",
                autoBind: false,
                dataSource: {
                    type: "json",
                    serverFiltering: true,
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            headers: {
                                "__RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val()
                            },
                            type: "Post",
                            dataType: "json",
                            url: "/Supervision/Tracking/GetCities"
                        }
                    },
                    schema: { data: 'Data' }

                }
            }).data("kendoDropDownList");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when I tried to debug it I faced something weird which was that the StateId is null.

I did a test using [Kendo UI jQuery DropDownList](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/editors/dropdownlist/overview?_ga=2.122361538.837763930.1605173621-1989278086.1527832522) with ASP.NET Core WebAPI as a back-end service, I can reproduce same issue.

Based on the formdata of the request that JS client made, to make ASP.NET Core endpoint can accept and handle these data well, you can try the following workaround.

*Custom model classes*

```
public class DataSourceRequestForCore
{
    public int Take { get; set; }
    public int Skip { get; set; }
    public FilterForCore filter { get; set; }
}

public class FilterForCore
{
    public string logic { get; set; }
    public List<FilterEntry> filters { get; set; }
}

public class FilterEntry
{
    [DataMember(Name = "field")]
    public string Field { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "operator")]
    public string Operator { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

*Action method*

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<JsonResult> GetCities(DataSourceRequestForCore request, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    request.Skip = 0;
    request.Take = 2000;

    //....
    //code logic here
```

Test Result

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @Fei Han. That's worked. Great...